# Gitlab CI: Accessing environment variables

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Consider the following gitlab-ci.yml:

```
...
variables:
  var_A: 'Hello'
before_script:
  - export var_B="World"
step1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - chmod u+x run.sh && source run.sh
```

Given that run.sh contains the following script:

```
echo $var_A
echo $var_B
```

I noticed after CI runs the pipeline, `var_A` resolves to "Hello", however calling `echo $var_B` doesn't print anything on the screen. What's exactly happening here? Is there any way to access var_b in the shell script?

Comment: This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774520/exporting-environment-variables-from-one-stage-to-the-next-in-gitlab-ci) and there is an [Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27921) still open

Answer (score 5):

If a process starts a child process and this child process sets environment variables, these variables are only visible in the child process and within children of the child process, they never propagate to the parent process, nor has the parent process an easy way to access the environment of its child process.

In case of a GitLab CI Runner, the runner will start a child process to run your script instructions, a shell (`/bin/sh` by default). When you change the environment in that shell, this change is only visible to the shell and to all child processes of the shell (e.g. commands you are executing).

Yet the shell running your `before_script` instructions doesn't have to be the same shell that later on runs your `script` instructions, usually these are two separate shells; especially as your `before_script` is global, so it runs once for all jobs, whereas all the jobs can run in parallel and thus all require own shells. The changes to the environment you made in one shell won't be visible to your code running in other shells later on.

As a work-around, you can use a file:

```
variables:
  var_A: 'Hello'
before_script:
  - echo 'export var_B="World"' > somefile.env
step1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - source somefile.env
    - chmod u+x run.sh && source run.sh
```

By the way, if you `source` a script file, it doen't need to be executable, so the `chmod` is not required. It would be required if you want to run the script as `./run.sh`. The difference is that `source` executes the script code in your current shell whereas `./run.sh` would create a child-shell and execute the code there. When running in a sub-shell, `run.sh` will see all your environment but changes to it will be private to `run.sh` and any process it calls, whereas these changes will propagate to your main shell if you do a `source run.sh`.