# Gitlab: Removing specific scheduled jobs from scheduled pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following jobs and stages and with this yml configuration the `test` stage runs on schedule and regular pipelines when I set `$RUN_JOB` variable to `true` in my schedule and in my project's CI/CD variables. But this also schedules `scheduled-test-1` and `scheduled-test-2` in my scheduled pipelines.

What I want to do is that the `test` stage should continue to run on schedule and regular pipelines but `scheduled-test-1` and `scheduled-test-2` should not be scheduled with `test` stage.

```
stages:
  build
  test
  deploy
  scheduled-test-1
  scheduled-test-2

build:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - develop
  except:
  - schedules

test:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
    variables:
    - $RUN_JOB

deploy:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - develop
  except:
  - schedules

scheduled-test-1:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - schedules

scheduled-test-2:
  script:
  - echo $Service_Version
  only:
  - schedules
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler option but, using [`artifacts:reports`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsreports) as in [Exporting environment variables from one stage to the next in GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046445/6309) might help.

The idea would be to export a `RUN_TEST` environment variable (a flag to signal the `test` job has been executed), and use it in the `scheduled-test-x` jobs in a rules section:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $RUN_TEST != ""
```

While those `scheduled-test-x` jobs might still be scheduled, at least they would not run, but their rule would be false.